# JavaScript code to deploy a contract (authentication)

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, javascript

When I run my contract deploy code in a browser (even if MetaMask is installed), I get this error:

```
authentication needed: password or unlock
```

The code follows:

```
var owner = $('#account').val();
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var contractInstance = contract.new(
    tokenName, tokenSymbol, { data: bytecode, from: owner, gas: 6721975 }
);
```

Please, please, explain how to do authentication for the user to be able to deploy my contract.

web3.js 0.20.6.

---

I connect to network with the following code:

```
    var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
    var web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Comment: If you're using MetaMask, I believe you shouldn't see that message. Can you share the code where you instantiate `web3`? My guess is you're not actually using MetaMask's provider and are still connecting to some other kind of node (maybe a local geth/parity instance) that requires a password to unlock the account.

Comment: @smarx Your guess is right: I connect MetaMask to my local Geth node and connect my Web app (which I am debugging) to the same Geth node. Should I connect MetaMask to Get and my Web app to MetaMask? (How to connect to MetaMask?)

Comment: @smarx I've edited the question as you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use MetaMask, you need code that looks like this:

```
var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

(MetaMask injects a `web3` global variable that has the right provider attached.)

To have MetaMask connect to your local geth node, just click the drop-down in the MetaMask UI that lets you choose your network. One of the options should be "localhost 8545." If you're not on that port, you can choose "custom RPC" and specify a URL.

Comment: OK, now it seems to work with MetaMask. But how to do it for users without MetaMask?

Comment: For users not running MetaMask (or Mist or some other web3 provider), I suppose they would need to run a local node (e.g. geth or parity) and keep an account there unlocked. But that's an extraordinary amount of trust for a user to place in your app, so hopefully users wouldn't do that.

Comment: Can't users without MetaMask just enter private key explicitly (without running a local node)?

Comment: They could, although giving your app their private key is just as dangerous as giving you access to a node with that account unlocked. To use a private key, you would need code to sign transactions locally and then broadcast them to a public node via `sendRawTransaction`/`sendSignedTransaction` (varies between web3.js versions). But again, users shouldn't trust you with their private keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it up like so:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // Use one of those accounts to deploy contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      arguments: ['hi there']
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

  inbox.setProvider(provider);
});
```